# How to pass DateTime object to javascript date object via json and twig

Tags: javascript, php, json, datetime, twig

For example, I have object which has `DateTime` object in php.

`in php`

```
    array_push($events,
    array(
        "date" => new \DateTime('2017-08-01'),
        "description" => "This is description of an event"
    ));
    array_push($events,
        array(
        "date" => new \DateTime('2017-07-19'),
        "description" => "Some longer\ntext can also\n be added"
        ));
```

parse the object like this.

`in twig`

```
{% for var, value in events %}
var {{var}} = {{ value|json_encode|raw }};
{% endfor %}
```

`output`

```
var 0 = {"date":{"date":"2017-08-01 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Tokyo"},"description":"This is description of an event"};
var 1 = {"date":{"date":"2017-07-19 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Tokyo"},"description":"Some longer\ntext can also\n be added"};
```

in this way `text` and `boolean` works well but can't convert DateTime to javascript object.

Is there any good solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use your datetime string from JSON to instantiate a `Date` object like so:

```
var d = new Date('2017-08-01 00:00:00.000000');
```

This can then be used like so, for example:

```
alert(d.toString()); //Tue Aug 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
```

Comment: THanks I found out that Date class constructor can take many kind of strings.